# C# application crashes silently due to Visual Studio generated code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crash, crash-reports

I created a simple application that I would really love to deploy, however whenever I installed the application on another machine that is not mine, the application crashes silently. As in no error is thrown or any notification that the application failed. Further research on the issue led me to view the error logs that windows keeps. I followed the exception `<SystemArgument>` down right to the codes in the application but I don't know what to do because any changes I make will be overwritten the next time I build.Here is what I got from the error logs:

**EventData**:

```
Application: bbcg.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
```

*Exception*:

> Info: System.ArgumentException Stack: at MS.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagerWrapper.GetStream(System.String) at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.EnsureResourceLocationSet() at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetContentTypeCore() at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.get_ContentType() at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri) at Report_Form_Generator.App.InitializeComponent() at Report_Form_Generator.App.Main()

I am out of Ideas and any help would be of great importance. How do I avoid this error?

Comment: It crashes at `ResourceManagerWrapper.GetStream`, resource related problem (languages? different version of windows? etc.). Search for just that to hopefully find your case: [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26027415/1997232).

Comment: I'll try forcing it at the manifest to only use .net 4.5

Comment: Have you tried running as "Run as administrator", It will give you more information about crashes.

Comment: @Sinatr yeah Language was the problem. I din't realize that in Assembly information the Neutral language was NOT None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Neutral Language in your apps Assembly Information, from project properties to None.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `UnhandledException` and `ThreadException` exception handlers in your application to catch unhandled exceptions and get further information about the error:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
    Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
}

static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs ex)
{
    // log the exception  or do other work
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs ex)
{
     // log the exception or do other work
}
```